# Can I develop .NET application using Virtual Box on Ubuntu?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu installed on my system. Now I have a project to do using Visual Studio in C#.
I want to know whether I can install Windows inside a Virtual Box and then install Visual Studio. Will I be able to develop Csharp application in a virtual environment? Will the Virtual Box support the running of Visual Studio software?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. I've done this.
You can install a Windows vm in VirtualBox.
Using Visual Studio doesn't depend on whether your Windows is a virtual machine or not.